# UV Unwrapping seams

Tags: uv

Where to put seams in this model? I am newbie.
I want to apply this acacia wood texture on this model. [image: Where to Put seams][image]

---

Thanks Blunder for providing very detailed information.

I am looking forward to your feedback on my first ever rendering. Please let me know how can I improve? (while reviewing, please overlook same texture on all coasters, as I have not applied array, mirror modifier)

[image: UV unwrapping coaster stand]

[image: rendered image]
[image: question]

Comment: This is the part that you have to find out by yourself. Every mesh is unique, but the process is always the same. Set seams, make a unwrap, have a look for distortions, make further modifications. Repeat until satisfied with the distortions. Then have a look how to arrange the UV patches. Use as few UV patches as possible since every seam means cleanup afterwards. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to be believable/realistic, you should let the UV islands follow the wood grain so that it looks like two wooden boards:

[image: example 2]

<sup>Model was separated for better visualization</sup>

You did a good job unwrapping the model. Just forgot here the tiny edge to mark as a seam. In consequence, Blender couldn't make a straight UV island but a ring and this introduces distortion (might be not bad for the hole and the cut edges of the board).

[image: missing seam]

The used texture is not seamless. That means if you place a UV island outside of the texture it wraps around and continues on the opposite side of the texture with a visible seam. If you don't like this you need to place the island completely on the texture.

[image: visible seam]

If you move the island up there is no visible seam because the whole texture is used in one piece:

[image: no visible seam]

Of course, where UV islands separate there will be seams too. Seamless textures do not have this drawback but may have noticable repeating patterns.

Comment: Should I have to make this in 2 seprate objects and after that smart uv project? Please have a look at my blend file. 
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1prTTuwEhJZchJkRDaPE_si_eMljrr3qm/view?usp=sharing (Please put correct seam of my model so that I can learn)

Comment: I cannot download your blend file, it's private. You need to make it public. -- No, you don't need to separate it into 2 objects. I've just done this so you can see it better. The seams are the red lines. They go around at the bottom of the first board and at the edges to unwrap the cube-shaped boards.

Comment: I have make the file public. Thanks for your valuable reply.

Comment: Thanks. The seams look good. You just forgot a tiny one and maybe you want to move up one of the islands. I've updated the answer above.